# Symphony Embedded Chat module not working

Tags: javascript

I have been set up with an account on a corporate Symphony chat system, and have been provided a subdomain (xxx.symphony.com) and a streamId (which I found by logging into a chatroom, clicking the date stamp of a message and viewing the Message Status pane).

I have been following the instructions for [Embedded Chat Module - Direct iFrame Rendering](https://embedding-api.symphony.com/docs/symphony-embedded-chat-module#section-direct-iframe-rendering), with the aim of embedding a Symphony chat into a web page.

I've put an iFrame on my web page, with the appropriate subdomain and streamId.

When the page loads, I get many Javascript errors:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sandbox' of undefined
...
TypeError: this.account.getTheme is not a function
...
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getExtension' of undefined

r {message: "Internal Server Error", name: "HTTPError", stack: "Error↵    at new r (https://<MY SUBDOMAIN>.symphony.com…s?4a001d68050fb0fd4c0d:85:984)↵    at <anonymous>", lifecycle: {…}}
lifecycle
:
{res: {…}, req: {…}}
message
:
"Internal Server Error"
name
:
"HTTPError"
stack
:
"Error↵    at new r (https://<MY SUBDOMAIN>.symphony.com/embed/bundle.js?4a001d68050fb0fd4c0d:114:11278)↵    at r (https://<MY SUBDOMAIN>.symphony.com/embed/bundle.js?4a001d68050fb0fd4c0d:171:606811)↵    at a (https://<MY SUBDOMAIN>.symphony.com/embed/bundle.js?4a001d68050fb0fd4c0d:85:72778)↵    at a._settlePromiseFromHandler (https://<MY SUBDOMAIN>.symphony.com/embed/bundle.js?4a001d68050fb0fd4c0d:85:46184)↵    at a._settlePromise (https://<MY SUBDOMAIN>.symphony.com/embed/bundle.js?4a001d68050fb0fd4c0d:85:46984)↵    at a._settlePromise0 (https://<MY SUBDOMAIN>.symphony.com/embed/bundle.js?4a001d68050fb0fd4c0d:85:47683)↵    at a._settlePromises (https://<MY SUBDOMAIN>.symphony.com/embed/bundle.js?4a001d68050fb0fd4c0d:85:49010)↵    at i._drainQueue (https://<MY SUBDOMAIN>.symphony.com/embed/bundle.js?4a001d68050fb0fd4c0d:85:2790)↵    at i._drainQueues (https://<MY SUBDOMAIN>.symphony.com/embed/bundle.js?4a001d68050fb0fd4c0d:85:2851)↵    at drainQueues (https://<MY SUBDOMAIN>.symphony.com/embed/bundle.js?4a001d68050fb0fd4c0d:85:984)↵    at <anonymous>"
__proto__
:
Error
```

And a 500 error:

```
https://<MY SUBDOMAIN>.symphony.com/webcontroller/api/v3/im/session?threadid=<MY THREAD ID> 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong here and how to fix it?

It seems like the Javascript might not be loading correctly, so perhaps there's some kind of cross-domain issue and/or a token I need.

(Note: I will be contacting Symphony's support about this soon, and if I find the solution that way, I'll be sure to post it.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what `iframe` input you used and if you found the solution, I am sure you did.

To help and provide an example, see below.

`iframe` Embedded Chat Module (ECM):

```
<html><head><title>Public</title>

</head><body>
<iframe src="https://<privatePod>.symphony.com/embed/?streamId=<streamID in base64>&amp;module=room&amp;mode=light&amp;font=xsmall" height="800" width="100%"></iframe>
</body></html>
```

**To obtain the URLSafe Base64 Conversation ID:**

- Replace forward slashes `/` with underscores `_`
- Replace pluses `+` with minuses `-`
- Ignore any trailing equal signs `=`

For example, the URLSafe Base64 encoding of

```
lX1hwfmQ+AK/k/a/BB0y2n///q2+0KfbdA==
```

converts to

```
lX1hwfmQ-AK_k_a_BB0y2n___q2-0KfbdA
```